# PhoneGap android splash screen going to black screen on slow devices

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am trying to get Android splash screens working in PhoneGap 3.0.0.

I've correctly added the following code in the `onCreate` method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set the splash screen
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);

    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 3000);
}
```

And the splash screen IS displaying for 3s. The issue occurs on devices where 3s is not long enough for the `deviceready` callback to be called. They are greeted with a black screen after the 3s of splash screen is shown.

I want the splash screen to be up for as long as it takes to fire the `deviceready` callback. Can I just put a very long time in the `super.loadUrl` method (say `50000`) and then in the `deviceready` callback... hide it using `navigator.splashscreen.hide();` ?

I've tried that, but it breaks the splash screen on iOS.

Any ideas?

Comment: try this...        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 10000);

Comment: That just causes the splash-screen to display for 10s. I want it to display for as long as it needs to display.

Comment: ok than you try with hide() and show() method